# Parsing JSON from IMDb API

Tags: jquery, json, api, jsonp, imdb

I found a way to extract data about TV shows or movies from IMDb in a comfortable JSON format: 
http://imdbapi.com/?t=query.

It's pretty awesome but when I try to actually use the data with local JS, it doesn't work.

```
var data = $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  async: false, 
  cache: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  jsonp: true,
  url: "http://imdbapi.com/?t=lost", 
  success: function() {
    console.log( 'loaded successfuly. ' )
  },
});
var poster = data.Poster;
console.log( poster );
```

I'm using JSONP because of CORS. Here's what the console shows:

"loaded successfuly.
undefined"

I don't know what is the problem! Please help. 

- Oren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use data it might not been setted.... well this is the case ;). To be sure put your code in the success method.

```
 $.ajax({
dataType: "json",
  async: false, 
  cache: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  jsonp: true,
  url: "http://imdbapi.com/?t=lost", 
  success: function(data) {

    var poster = data.Poster;
    console.log(poster);
    console.log( 'loaded successfuly. ')
  },
});
```

Comment: copy/paste then too lazy to correct it the right way. I edited, now you've got it.

Comment: imdbapi.com is not working anymore use this one http://www.theimdbapi.org/